# How to get all checked cells from checkboxes in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a goolesheets that contains checkboxes.  I would like to get all checked cells using google apps script. For example, as below picture, I would like to get a result of 'A3', 'A6' and 'A9'.

[image: googlesheets checkbox]

I tried many different ways and I found a script below but it only gives me the last cell, which is 'A9'.

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
var range = '';
var sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();

for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
 range += sel[i].getA1Notation() + ', ';
}
Logger.log(range);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your current solution uses `getSelection` which means if you select the desired cells manually:

[image]

you will get `A3, A9, A6,` which based on your code is the correct answer. Although, I guess you don't want to manually select them, otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use a script to find them.

**Side Note:**

If you want to use that solution, I assume you want `A3, A9, A6` instead of `A3, A9, A6,` so this would make more sense:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sel = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  const range = []; 

  for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){
    range.push(sel[i].getA1Notation());
  }
  Logger.log(range.join(', '));          
}
```

assuming again you have selected the checkboxes as in the screenshot.

### Solution:

In the below solution, adjust `Sheet1` to the name of your sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of your sheet here
  const colA = sh.getRange('A1:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const range=colA.map((c,i)=>c==true?`A${i+1}`:'').filter(c=>c!='').join(', ');
  Logger.log(range); // A3, A6, A9          
}
```

In this solution, we are getting all the values of column `A`, then using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we get the cell reference of the `true` cells (checkbox is clicked) and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing on these values.

Comment: Hi Marios, thanks for your answer. It seems works for me. I will see if I can apply this to project. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your scenario and did some changes in your code specifically in the declaration of the sheet and data range to be checked. For the solution, I changed your loop and added a condition inside to check for *true*(ticked checkbox) values.

Please see my code below. This is working fine on my end. Note that this is assuming that you only have your checkboxes on column A.

```
function myFunction() {
  var range = '';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var val = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for(row in val){
    if(val[row][0]==true){
      range += 'A'+ (parseInt(row) + 1) + ',';
    }
  }
  Logger.log(range);
}
```

Comment: Yes Jason, this is another way to get it working for sure. This is actually more readable for me haha. Appreciate your answer!

Comment: That's good to hear. :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers